# How to border a bar for particular data aperiod in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataset of a year and its numerical description. Example:

```
X     Y
1890  6
1900  4
2000  1
2010  9
```

I plot a bar like `plt.bar(X,Y)` and it looks like:
[image]

How can I make the step of the X scale more detailet, for example, 2 years?
Can I border somehow every 5 years with another color, red, for instatnce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some different ways to do this. This is a possible solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1890,1900,2000,2010]
y = [6,4,1,9]
stepsize = 10 # Chose your step here
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x,y)
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, stepsize))
plt.show()
```

, the result is:

[image: Setting xticks for bar plot]